# Creating a new db if the scheme changed

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How do I create a new realm database if the current fails?
I read somewhere its possible with new versions of realm but i didnt find anything.

```
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let realmPath = "\(documentsDirectory)/db.realm"
let url = URL(string: realmPath)
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: url, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: nil, objectTypes: nil)
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm's `Configuration` struct has a property `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`, this is probably what you are looking for.

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: url, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: nil, objectTypes: nil)
config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

It deletes and recreates the Realm file with the new schema if a migration is needed.

See the docs: https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.0.2/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration28deleteRealmIfMigrationNeededSb